# create 3d array or 3d matrix

Tags: c#, matrix, multidimensional-array

I try to create an 3d array with 2 for loops. But If I check my Z component, my Console will give me 2 values.

why? and what can I change? 
Normally I would use `List<Tuple<,,>>` but I want to create an 3D Matrix so I thought float[,,] are better to convert.
Do you have an idea how to do this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float[,,] A = new float[40, 48,40*48];
            List<Tuple<int,int,float>> P = new List<Tuple<int, int, float>>();
            var Zvalue = new float[40*48];
            int i = 0;
            Random R = new Random();
            for(int y = 0; y <= 47; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x <= 39; x++)
                {
                    Zvalue[i] = R.Next(0, 10);
                    //P[x, y, i] = { { { (x,y,Z[x,y]) } } };
                    P.Add(Tuple.Create(x, y, Zvalue[i]));
                    A[x,y,i] =  Zvalue[i];
                    Console.WriteLine(A[x,y,i]);
                    Console.Read();
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Console Output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qmb66.png)

After the comments I understood it as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            float[,,] A = new float[40, 48, 120];
            List<Tuple<int, int, float>> P = new List<Tuple<int, int, float>>();
            var Zvalue = new float[40 * 48 * 120];
            int i = 0;
            Random R = new Random();
            for (int y = 0; y <= 47; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x <= 39; x++)
                {
                    for (int z = 0; z < 120; z++)
                    {
                        Zvalue[i] = R.Next(0, 10);
                        //P[x, y, i] = { { { (x,y,Z[x,y]) } } };
                        P.Add(Tuple.Create(x, y, Zvalue[i]));
                        A[x, y, z] = Zvalue[i];
                        Console.WriteLine(A[x, y, z]);
                        Console.Read();
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Assumed that for every x,y Position there will be 120 possible Z-Positions. Is it correct ? Also could I use this `float[,,] A` for matrices calculations? 
But I haven't understood why do `Console.Read()` gets 2 characters?

Ok it isn't correct as there are random values for 0,0,0 until 0,0,119 but that's it. For example for 0,1,0 the value is 0. How can I fix it ?

Comment: Your snippet makes no sense. What are you even trying to do?

Comment: What do you mean by _"But If I check my Z component, my Console will give me 2 values. "_  - your code displays only single values

Comment: I try to create a 3d matrix with Postion x,y and Value Z. Value Z is as an example a Random Value from 0 to 10.

Comment: A 3d matrix have positions x, y, and z, and each value has an "address" composed of three positions. Think of a cude that's composed of smaller, equal cubes. each value is inside one small cube, and it's address is the index of the cube from all 3 ways - length, width and height.

Comment: How could I implement it with for loops?

Comment: @PaulF I've explained what a 3d matrix is since the OP seems to misunderstand the concept :-)

Comment: @T.molklein You mean populate it? basically, it's a loop for each dimension, so use 3 level nested for loops.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: my apologies - I only noticed the following comment & didn't notice the explanation was by someone different.

Comment: Your code is outputting two values at a time simply because Console.Read() is getting 2 characters in the buffer when you press enter (cr & lf) - if you press the space key 10 time & then the enter key you will get a group of 12 numbers printed. Your code is essentially correct except it needs a third loop as described by @ZoharPeled

Comment: So I understood it as follows: